# Ionic Angular Capacitor - FileOpener Activity Not Found: No Activity found to handle intent

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have an Angular 12 Capacitor application where i am trying to open a downloaded file in whichever native app the user choses.

I am using ionic-native/File and ionic-native/FileOpener

```
const dataType = event.body.type;
          const binaryData = [];
          binaryData.push(event.body);

          if (this.platform.is('mobile') && this.platform.is('capacitor')) {
            // running native mobile, try and open file
            console.log('mobile open file');
            const blob = new Blob(binaryData, { type: dataType });
            this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory, attachment.name, blob, {replace: true}).then(() => {
              console.log('file should be saved');
              this.fileOpener.open(this.file.dataDirectory + attachment.name, dataType).then(() => console.log('file should be open'));
            });
          } else {
            // not running native mobile, download the attachment
            const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
            downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, { type: dataType }));
            downloadLink.setAttribute('download', attachment.name);
            downloadLink.setAttribute('target', '_self');
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
            downloadLink.click();
          }
```

However, every time fileopener.open is called i get an error saying  Activity Not Found: No Activity found to handle intent.  Below are the logs

```
I/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/main.js - Line 3580 - Msg: mobile open file
V/Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: File189568326, service: File, action: resolveLocalFileSystemURI, actionArgs: ["file:\/\/\/data\/user\/0\/com.company.appname\/files\/"]
V/Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: File189568327, service: File, action: getFile, actionArgs: ["cdvfile:\/\/localhost\/files\/","1635956966683.jpeg",{"create":true,"exclusive":false}]
V/Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: File189568328, service: File, action: getFileMetadata, actionArgs: ["cdvfile:\/\/localhost\/files\/1635956966683.jpeg"]
V/Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: File189568329, service: File, action: write, actionArgs: ["cdvfile:\/\/localhost\/files\/1635956966683.jpeg","{data removed}"
I/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/main.js - Line 3583 - Msg: file should be saved
V/Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: FileOpener2189568330, service: FileOpener2, action: open, actionArgs: ["file:\/\/\/data\/user\/0\/com.company.appname\/files\/1635956966683.jpeg","application\/octet-stream"]
E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/vendor.js - Line 48142 - Msg: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"status":9,"message":"Activity not found: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.company.appname.fileOpener2.provider/files/1635956966683.jpeg typ=application/octet-stream flg=0x3 }"}
```

My assumption is that i need some intent-filter for the android.intent.action.VIEW added to my AndroidManifest.xml but I have no idea for what.  Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.appname">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">


        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name="com.company.appname.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the error message is actually a cryptic one.  It actually as nothing to do with Intents and the AndroidManifest.xml.   No the actual issue is the MIMEType for the fileOpener.open() call.   The Type that was being passed in was application/octet-stream which the native device has no applications that can open that type, so it throws an error.  Since this file was a jpeg i changed it to image/jpeg and it opened perfectly.   Here is the updated code

```
            this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory, attachment.name, blob, { replace: true }).then(() => {
              console.log('file should be saved');
              this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(this.file.dataDirectory + attachment.name).then(fileInfo => {
                const files = fileInfo as FileEntry;
                files.file(success => {
                  this.fileOpener.open(this.file.dataDirectory + attachment.name, success.type).then(() => console.log('file should be open'));
                });
              });
            });
```

I added in the file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl() as this call basically gets the meta about the stored file.  you can then get the type of the file and pass that in the fileopener.open()